# Installing Windows 7 on SSD in optical bay caddy

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have a [Dell Vostro 3450](http://www.dell.com/content/products/productdetails.aspx/vostro-3450?c=us&l=en) in which I inserted Samsung 840 SSD in the optical bay caddy addition to the HDD. I wanted to install Windows 7 on the SSD but apparently you can’t load the OS from a removable drive; I guess that’s how Windows 7 sees the SSD? My bios recognizes the SSD and it’s enabled as AHCI. I have done clean all to both drives and did a clean install of windows.

The obvious solution is to switch places between the HDD and SSD but Dell have built this laptop in such a way that you have to take the whole damn thing apart in order to get to the HDD.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how to boot this SSD when it’s mounted in the optical drive bay?

Comment: I have done the same thing in a Dell E6500 and it worked flawlessly the first time. Which makes me curious: Exactly why does it fail for you. What is the literal error message?

Answer (score 0):

It will install from a bootable usb, mine asked CD drivers but was happy to browse the same CD to look for them! If you use a USB chip be sure to remove it at the first restart or the whole process will restart!

Comment: Huudi, he is asking how to install **on** a HDD/SDD. Not how to install **from** something without a DVD.